# How to aggregate items binaries in a pandas column based on groupby on other two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have the following pandas df

```
Year    ID    Participated    Participation_Count
2016    1         0                    0
2016    1         0                    0 
2016    1         1                    1 
2016    1         0                    1
2017    1         1                    1
2017    1         0                    1 
2017    1         0                    1
2017    1         0                    1
2018    1         1                    1
2018    1         1                    2
2018    1         1                    3
2018    1         0                    3
2016    2         0                    0 
2016    2         0                    0
2016    2         0                    0
2016    2         0                    0
2017    2         0                    0
2017    2         0                    0
2017    2         1                    1
2017    2         1                    2
2018    2         1                    1
2018    2         1                    2
2018    2         1                    3
2018    2         1                    4
```

How could I create the participation count column that looks at the sum of the participation for a given ID and year.

Thank you!

Comment: Is `Participated` supposed to be used somewhere, or are you just after: `df.groupby(['ID', 'Year'])['Participation_Count'].sum()` ?

Comment: Its going to be used somewhere. Im looking to create a new column with the participation count and I know I need to do a groupby on the ID and year but not sure how to create that aggregation and add the participation count column to my dataframe.

Comment: Well.. the code above will aggregate... but not sure what you mean by add it to your dataframe... I mean you could do: `df['my_new_col'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Year'])['Participation_Count'].transform('sum') ` but that doesn't seem all that warranted... could you explain what you're trying to achieve with a smaller sample and an example of the output? That'd help.

Comment: I think I figured it out. df['Participation_Count']=df.groupby(['ID','Year'])['Participated '].cumsum(). By add it to my dataframe I mean that I have the first three columns (Year, ID and participated). For every year and ID i need to have a count of the number of times participated is 1. The final output is what Ive shown in the table above.

Comment: Ahh... sorry... mis-read your Q - I thought you already had that column and that was what you're working with... in that case... what you've come up with seems 'bout right.